# python schedule at server time synced with my country

Tags: python, timezone, timezone-offset

I'm writing a Python script, and I need to use the Python [schedule](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/schedule) module.

I want to execute a job every day at midnight, so I wrote something like

`schedule.every().day.at("00:00")`

Problem is that I want to run at ***my*** midnight, because I'm uploading this script to a server and I don't know its location and hence its timezone.

How could I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from time import gmtime, strftime
print strftime("%z", gmtime())
```

Pacific Standard Time

```
import time
time.tzname
```

it returns a tuple of two strings: the first is the name of the local non-DST timezone, the second is the name of the local DST timezone.

Answer (score 1):

Schedule doesn't support timezones, a [pull-request](https://github.com/dbader/schedule/pull/16) that included the initial changes to support that was rejected (the source for that can be found [here](https://github.com/dbader/schedule/pull/16/commits/5d98d2dc6c408841d9b96c1b627c1caba214db7c)).

So either look at those changes, or run something at 00:00 that emails you a message, so you can deduct how much the offset from that server is to yours.
If you do so check on a regular basis especially late October/March, so you can determine if the server is subject to daylight saving changes for its localtime, and adjust accordingly.